# # of windows opened in the Dock indication?

Tags: dock

I just got a new macbook pro (used to use a dual boot linux/windows system). I'm still getting used to some of the features.

One thing I've noticed is when an application is open, it would show in the dock at the bottom of the screen and there would be a dot below the icon indicating that it is open. WHen open instances of the same app is open, there is no visible indication of how many instances are open. Is there any way to enable this? For example if I had 3 google chromes open, I'd like to be able to see in the dock that there are 3 open without having to right click on the icon. Perhaps 3 dots would show instead of one dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple only provides **Mission Control** (<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>) and **Application Windows** (formerly **Exposé**: <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>) for window management. Yes, this was (and still is) my least favorite change after switching to macOS.

Under **** → **System Preferences** → **Dock**, you may also uncheck *Minimize windows into application icon* to avoid “losing” minimized windows, but this can quickly clutter your Dock.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was aware of mission control, but not application windows, though both of them just seems to show every window I have open. Hopefully in the future they might add more dots to indicate the # of instances you have open.

Comment: They aren't really instances in the way they would be in windows, no Mac apps are, hence the presence of one icon. If you truly opened more than one instance, more icons would actually appear. But that's not what normally happens.